# Using Twitter OAuth to post updates automatically

Tags: twitter, oauth

Here's my scenario.

I have a web site, which automatically posts updates to Twitter using cURL at the moment.

But I hear Twitter is going to turn this feature off and move to OAuth.

I tried implementing OAuth in my site, but the user actually has to manually authenticate before being able to post anything to twitter.

How can I use OAuth and still let my website post updates automatically, without me having to manually click on "authenticate"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using a single Twitter account have a look at this page: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token

Answer (score 1):

You can post updates automatically with OAuth.  The token [does not expire](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ#Howlongdoesanaccesstokenlast) automatically, so you can store it in the database and use it repeatedly later.

Comment: Hi I just tried this, but no success. I saved the tokens, but when I access, it still asks me to put user name and password. why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter offers you single accesss token and its ideal for those applications migrating to OAuth with single-user use cases. [Tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) describes how to get started using OAuth directly with an access token.

[Here](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/) is an example shows how to implement Twitter OAuth with .NET and attached sample code.